# Pyspark; iterate over dataframe to sum group based on date filters

Tags: python, loops, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data frame that looks like the below. Not all customers have purchase recorded in each year and month combination. 
I want to iterate through and sum purchases made in Last 3 months, 6 months and 12 months.

I cannot insert new rows for missing months as my dataset is very large.

Things I have tried
a) Convert year and month to date 
b) Use sum and case when, which didn't work. 
c) Used iterate over rows to sum but the date I created was timestamp and subtracting to day kept giving errors.

Input

```
Customer_ID, Purchase_Year, Purchase_Month, Purchases
1 2019 1 4
1 2019 2 6
1 2019 3 4
1 2019 4 2
2 2019 1 2
2 2019 5 3
3 2019 1 9
```

Expected Output

```
Customer_ID, Purchase_Year, Purchase_Month, Purchases, L3M
1 2019 1 4 4
1 2019 2 6 10
1 2019 3 4 14
1 2019 4 2 12
2 2019 1 2 2
2 2019 5 3 3
3 2019 1 9 9
```

My initial attempt which works (but not for missing rows)

```
sqlContext.sql("""select *, sum(Purchases) over (partition by customer_id
                          order by Purchase_Year, Purchase_Month
                           rows between 3 preceding and current row) as total_s
 from customer""").show()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the approach you had earlier using timestamps was correct, because if your last6 months goes to 2018, then how would you go from 2019 to 2018 using purchase year and purchase month.

You could convert the timestamp to long and then use rangebetween in a window function to traverse as many days you want, for your 3months, you could use 89 from current day(90 total).

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
days= lambda i: i * 86400
w=Window().partitionBy("Customer_ID").orderBy("sec").rangeBetween(-days(89),0)
df.withColumn("sec", F.to_timestamp(F.concat("Purchase_Year","Purchase_Month"),"yyyyM").cast("long"))\
  .withColumn("L3", F.sum("Purchases").over(w)).orderBy("Customer_ID","Purchase_Month").drop("sec").show()

+-----------+-------------+--------------+---------+---+
|Customer_ID|Purchase_Year|Purchase_Month|Purchases| L3|
+-----------+-------------+--------------+---------+---+
|          1|         2019|             1|        4|  4|
|          1|         2019|             2|        6| 10|
|          1|         2019|             3|        4| 14|
|          1|         2019|             4|        2| 12|
|          2|         2019|             1|        2|  2|
|          2|         2019|             5|        3|  3|
|          3|         2019|             1|        9|  9|
+-----------+-------------+--------------+---------+---+
```

Comment: This works perfectly for what I am trying to do. I understand your comment on rangebetween seeing your implementation, thanks a lot. Still learning, so can you kindly explain what sec does in the above? If I extend it to 6 months, would I define another window function and extend the line of code below  .withColumn("L6", F.sum("Purchases").over(w2)).orderBy("Customer_ID","Purchase_Month").drop("sec") where w2=Window().partitionBy("Customer_ID").orderBy("sec").rangeBetween(-days(119),0)

Comment: sec is basically your timestamp in seconds. and the lambda function computes days by multiplying your seconds by 86400(60*60*24). Yes you got the w2 correct. Id just like to say that after making these windows I would still recommend you to verify the values, and see if they fit your case as months have different number of days, but for the most part this should do the trick, and is an industry standard for big data

Comment: 6 months should be 179 not 119. 6*30days=180

Comment: thanks a lot again. It does work across time ranges and results look right across several examples. Interesting, enjoy learning new stuff. Super helpful!